# Unable to convert Java code to Scala one

Tags: java, scala

What I want to do is to convert this code to Scala:

```
Object[] method1(Object obj) {
  if (obj instanceof int[]) {
    int sourceArr[] = (int[]) obj;
    Integer[] res = new Integer[sourceArr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceArr.length; i++)
       res[i] = sourceArr[i];

    return res;
  } 
    else if // and so on for double, int, boolean ...

    else if (obj instanceof Object[]) {
      return (Object[]) obj;
    } else {
      return new Object[] { obj };
    }
  }
```

Here is my attempt:

```
  def method1(obj: Any): Array[Any] = obj match {
    case x: Array[AnyRef] => x
    case x: Array[Int] => x
    // and so on for Double, Boolean, Char, Byte, Long....
    case _ => new Array[Any]()
  }
```

And the errors:

```
1) overloaded method constructor Array with alternatives:
[error]   (dim1: Int,dim2: Int,dim3: Int,dim4: Int,dim5: Int,dim6: Int,dim7: Int,dim8: Int,dim9: Int)Array[Any] <and>
[error]   (dim1: Int,dim2: Int,dim3: Int,dim4: Int,dim5: Int,dim6: Int,dim7: Int,dim8: Int)Array[Any] <and>
[error]   (dim1: Int,dim2: Int,dim3: Int,dim4: Int,dim5: Int,dim6: Int,dim7: Int)Array[Any] <and>
[error]   (dim1: Int,dim2: Int,dim3: Int,dim4: Int,dim5: Int,dim6: Int)Array[Any] <and>
[error]   (dim1: Int,dim2: Int,dim3: Int,dim4: Int,dim5: Int)Array[Any] <and>
[error]   (dim1: Int,dim2: Int,dim3: Int,dim4: Int)Array[Any] <and>
[error]   (dim1: Int,dim2: Int,dim3: Int)Array[Any] <and>
[error]   (dim1: Int,dim2: Int)Array[Any] <and>
[error]   (_length: Int)Array[Any]
[error]  cannot be applied to ()
[error]     case _ => new Array[Any]()

2) type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[Short]
[error]  required: Array[Any]
[error] Note: Short <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]     case x: Array[Short] => x

3) type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[Long]
[error]  required: Array[Any]
[error] Note: Long <: Any, but class Array is invariant in type T.
[error] You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: Any`. (SLS 3.2.10)
[error]     case x: Array[Long] => x

// and so on for each type I have -- Double, Boolean, Char, Byte, Long....
```

How do I solve this? Is there any more reasonable way to do that in Scala?
Notice that I can't change Java code.

Comment: The Java code is wrong.  A `float[]` is not an `Object[]`.  Do you mean `Object[] res = ...`?

Comment: @RexKerr, sorry, I don't see what's what's wrong with Java code. I edited it to make more exact, however.

Comment: @Rew Kerr: As wrong as it is, it is (sadly) valid java code, and potential inconsistencies are handled at runtime (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C.23).

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles - Argh.  Way to go, javac-type-checker!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the last case: it is unndeed because the other cases already cover all the possibilities (an `Any` can only be an `AnyVal` or an `AnyRef`).
Next, you should change the return type, because `Array` is invariant and thus the fact that `Int <: Any` (by example) does not mean that `Array[Int] <: Array[Any]`

```
def method1(obj: Any): Array[_] = obj match {
  case x: Array[AnyRef] => x
  case x: Array[Int] => x
  // and so on for Double, Boolean, Char, Byte, Long....
}
```

This will compile. However, that's probably still not what you meant. Your original java version performs a copy of the input array for primitive arrays, returns the array as is if it is an array of references, and finally wraps the input into a single element array if it was not an array in the first place. Your scala version does not do any of this.
So I think that what you want is simply this:

```
def method1(obj: Any): Array[_] = obj match {
  case x: Array[AnyRef] => x
  case x: Array[_] => x.clone()
  case x => Array( x )
}
```

Comment: that's great, it compiles. why did you use `case x => Array( x )`? Don't `case x: Array[AnyRef] => x` and `case x: Array[_] => x.clone()` cover all possible cases?

Comment: and also why `def method1(obj: Any): Array[_] ` instead of `def method1(obj: Any): Array[Any] `?

Comment: "... cover all possible cases?". I simply followed what your original code did. It corresponds to your last case in your java code (`return new Object[] { obj };`). "why def method1(obj: Any): Array[_] instead of def method1(obj: Any): Array[Any]". Because `Array` is  invariant, so (quoting myself) the fact that Int <: Any (by example) does not mean that Array[Int] <: Array[Any]. This is the reason for your type mismatch errors (by example Array[Short] is not convertible to Array[Any]). The equivalent java code compiles fine just because of a loophole in the java type system.

Answer (score 3):

In your Java code you have to repack the arrays, so you have to do the same in Scala also (though it's easy with `map`):

```
  case x: Array[Int] => x.map(_.asInstanceOf[Any])
```

(oh, and since you're returning `Any` not `AnyRef`, but both are really the same thing to the JVM, just look for the one you want to return.  So not:

```
  case x: Array[AnyRef] => x.asInstanceOf[Array[Any]]
```

but:

```
  case x: Array[Any] = x
```

)

And you are mixing up the constructor call to `Array`--which takes a single argument which is the length--with the `apply` method on the `Array` object, which lets you specify the contents.  You probably meant

```
  case _ => Array[Any]()
```

or if you actually wanted to wrap the object as in the Java code,

```
  case x => Array(x)
```

Comment: it seems to be correct, but I really didn't get what you meant. specifically, **So not: case x: Array[AnyRef] =>  x.asInstanceOf[Array[Any]] ** --> I don't have this. **but case x: Array[Any] = x** --> this is what I have, however, why did you say "but"? Can you please explain how do I have to change my code exactly?

Comment: @Grienders - You have, in your question, **case x: Array[AnyRef] => x** which is **NOT** the same.  One is typed as taking `Any` and the other as taking `AnyRef`.

Answer (score 1):

Try `new Array[AnyRef]()` instead. An `Object` is an `AnyRef` not an `Any`.

Regardless, you'll have to cast the result if `.asInstanceOf[Array[Any]]`. Java treats arrays as covariant, whereas Scala treats them as invariant.

Comment: ust one thing to clarify: Java's Object is Scala's Any, correct? Because all types (including Integer, Boolean and all reference types) in Java are inherited from Object, likewise in Scala -- from Any

Comment: @Grienders No, Java's `Object` is Scala's `AnyRef`, because Java types `int`, `boolean`, `double`, `float`, `char` and `short` do not inherit from `Object`, and `void` is not even a type in Java. You touched the very point when you said "all reference types". `AnyRef` is any reference type, whereas `Any` is any type, including the value types.